# How to reset `increment` value back to 1 when data changes?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

**Goal**

I am aiming to insert database records into MySQL using Python. But with an extra detail, I'll explain as I go along..

**This is my current script (Fully functional & working):**

```
#Get data from SQL
sqlCursor = mjmConnection.cursor()
sqlCursor.execute("SELECT sol.id, p.id, p.code,p.description, p.searchRef1, so.number, c.code, c.name, sol.requiredQty \
    FROM salesorderline sol JOIN \
    salesorder so \
    ON sol.salesorderid = so.id JOIN \
    product p \
    ON sol.productid = p.id JOIN \
    customer c \
    ON so.customerid = c.id \
    WHERE so.orderdate > DATEADD(dd,-35,CAST(GETDATE() AS date));")

#Send recieved data from SQL query from above to MySQL database
print("Sending MJM records to MySQL Database")
mjmCursorMysql = productionConnection.cursor()
for x in sqlCursor.fetchall():
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = x
    mjmCursorMysql.execute("INSERT ignore INTO mjm_python (id, product_id, product_code, product_description, product_weight, \
            salesorder_number, customer_code, customer_name, requiredQty) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i))


productionConnection.commit()
mjmCursorMysql.close()
sqlCursor.close()
```

**What it does**

The above script does the following:

1. Gets data from SQL Server
2. Inserts that data into MySQL

I have specifically used `IGNORE` in the MySQL query, to prevent duplicate `id` numbers.

Data will look like this:

[image]

**Next..**

Now - i'd like to add a column name `sales_id_increment`. This will start from `1` and increment for each same `salesorder_number` and reset back to `1` when there is a different `salesorder_number`. So I am wanting it to look something like this:

[image]

**Question**

How do I achieve this? Where do I need to look, in my Python script or the MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this column when you select the rows from SQL Server with window functions `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK()` (if there are duplicate ids):

```
SELECT sol.id, p.id, p.code,p.description, p.searchRef1, so.number, c.code, c.name, sol.requiredQty,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY so.number ORDER BY sol.id) sales_id_increment
FROM salesorderline sol 
JOIN salesorder so ON sol.salesorderid = so.id 
JOIN product p ON sol.productid = p.id 
JOIN customer c ON so.customerid = c.id 
WHERE so.orderdate > DATEADD(dd,-35,CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. I shall do my research to the query you have added, really short and simple is that! Much appriciated.

Comment: @LV98 I read in your question that maybe there are duplicates in the results of this query which will not be inserted by using IGNORE. If in this case you have gaps between the row numbers you may change to DENSE_RANK() window function.

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicate `id` numbers for each record as it is a foreign key. So all good. I'll also look into `dense_rank()` in my own time. Can I ask you - where did you learn SQL?

Comment: Keep it up forpas! :D